# Not able to use the mic on my bluetooth headset

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, microphone, headset

I use Ubuntu desktop 19.10. My bluetooth headphones - boAt Airdopes 201.

I connected to bluetooth but I am able to use my bluetooth headset only as speaker and not as mic.

After referring to various answers on askubuntu and similar platforms, I installed bluez-5.54, ofono-1.31, phonesim-1.21, pulseaudio-13.0 and blueman. Many answers say that blueman can solve this, but problem continues for me.

I am a noob on Linux.. Please help.

A piece of information: I use Ubuntu from a persistent bootable hard disk. Can this affect the functionality?